# Wrong local state value when a handling a window event (React)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom-events

I have a state value `ccFormDetails` with a an empty object as default value.

```
  const [ccFormDetails, setCCFormDetails] = useState({})
```

In first `useEffect`, I call a function the populates `ccFormDetails` with relevant data.

```
  const getCCFormData = async () => {
    const ccFormResult = await ContractService.getContractsCCFormData()
    const { ccFormData } = ccFormResult
    setCCFormDetails(ccFormData)
  }
```

In second `useEffect`, I create an a event named `message` and assign a `handleCgEvent` handler to it.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('message', handleCgEvent)
    return () => window.removeEventListener('message', handleCgEvent)
  }, [])
```

I'm rendering an `iframe` with a submit button that emits the `message` event when clicked.

Then, when I click the sumbit button in the `iframe`, the `handleCgEvent` handler fires and should extract the correct (updated, fecthed) value of `ccFormDetails`. (Which I can see populated correctly in the React components tree)

```
  const handleCgEvent = e => {
    if (e.data === 'reload_cg') {
      console.log('fail')
    }

    if (e.data['event_id'] === 'cg-success') {
      console.log('success')
      console.log('ccFormDetails1 ', ccFormDetails)
    }
  }
```

But what I get is `{}` meaning the original default state.
This should not happen per my knowledge of React.
Am I missing something/Does event handling messes state?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is you're using the `handleCgEvent` that's created when the component is mounted, and `ccFormDetails` is encapsulated within it using its default value. In order to get the most current state, you're going to have to use useRef. Something like:

```js
  const [ccFormDetails, setCCFormDetails] = useState({})
  const formRef = useRef();

  formRef.current = ccFormDetails;

  const handleCgEvent = e => {
    if (e.data === 'reload_cg') {
      console.log('fail')
    }

    if (e.data['event_id'] === 'cg-success') {
      console.log('success')
      console.log('ccFormDetails1 ', formRef.current)
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('message', handleCgEvent)
    return () => window.removeEventListener('message', handleCgEvent)
  }, []);
```

If it's okay for you to add and remove the event listener, then I would just add `[ccFormDetails]` as a dependency, assuming the entire object is recreated when its properties change.

For further reading about stale values in closures, this is a great blog entry: https://dmitripavlutin.com/react-hooks-stale-closures/

Comment: Thanks a lot. Really appreciated